# A real life riddle

Tags: science

Suppose you are in a boat on a pond and you are holding a small 10 lb weight. You drop the weight into the water. Does the water level rise, stay the same, or lower?

Answer (score 2):

When the weight is in the water

> it displaces the same volume of water as itself.

When it is in the boat

> it causes the boat to display a volume of water with the same mass as itself.

Since

> the weight is presumably denser than water,

when you drop it in

> it will displace *less* water and the level of water in the pond will therefore sink.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for being stupid. I'm on mobile and couldn't find the search function easily. Clearly I'm blind, and that's no excuse anyway.

Comment: No apology needed -- oversights are easy :-).